# JQuery autocomplete json_encode custom display

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, json

This is driving me slightly crazy.

I am proficient in getting a single Ajax request / autocomplete.

However, now I am trying get a multi-column result working.
I am combining: [Autocomplete Remote](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) and [Custom Display.](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) from the JQuery autocomplete examples.

The `json_encoded` array returns a string looks like:

a)

```
[
    {"value":"myvalue1","label":"mylabel1","desc":"mydescription1"},
    {"value":"myvalue2","label":"mylabel2","desc":"mydescription2"}
]
```

The Autocomplete remote shows a different formatting. *Should it be:*

b)

```
[
    {value:"myvalue1",label:"mylabel1",desc:"mydescription1"},
    {value:"myvalue2",label:"mylabel2",desc:"mydescription2"}
]
```

Which is the correct format - a or b? I am hoping "a", because it requires less code.

Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate all the responses. If you can help with part 2 of this, please take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300908/jquery-autocomplete-custom-display-multi-column-part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the correct version is the first one, A, the second is not a valid JSON as it doesn't pass the [validation](http://jsonlint.com/). you must put `"` before the keys/properties

For example this is the json that is returned from the jQuery demo:

```
[
    {
        "id": "Coccothraustes coccothraustes",
        "label": "Hawfinch",
        "value": "Hawfinch"
    },
    {
        "id": "Accipiter gentilis",
        "label": "Northern Goshawk",
        "value": "Northern Goshawk"
    },
    {
        "id": "Accipiter nisus",
        "label": "Eurasian Sparrow Hawk",
        "value": "Eurasian Sparrow Hawk"
    },
    {
        "id": "Surnia ulula",
        "label": "Northern Hawk Owl",
        "value": "Northern Hawk Owl"
    }
]
```

Comment: I had forgotten all about jsonlint so thank you for the reminder. I will assume the autocomplete will work with this, based on your code example from JQ UI's website. I wonder why they used two different formats??  Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You should be putting quotes around your keys/properties

`{"foo":"bar"}` is recommended over `{foo:"bar"}`

http://ejohn.org/blog/the-state-of-json/

http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/

Comment: This answer was also correct, but the link provided in the answer below were more definitive for me personally. If I could award 2 correct answers, I would.

Comment: Cool. What link did he provide?

Answer (score -1):

it should be B if you want the plugin does something like `obj.value` or `obj.label`

Comment: B is not a valid Json i think

Comment: I will be using .value so hopefully validated json will work ok too.