# JQuery Autocomplete Custom Display Multi-column Part 2

Tags: jquery, json, user-interface, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to get an autocomplete similiar to:
[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#custom-data) at jquery ui in their custom example.

This instead will use an ajax call instead of hard-coded data. I have two columns that I wish to show (a value and description). As the user is typing it in, the .val() is passed to the ajax page, and it provides the suggestions. One the first column will be used for the value.

I was able to get a single column returned using a simple one-column example, but not multiple values. I am thinking it is something simple, since it is a re-hash of example code. Your help is appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#myinputbox').autocomplete({ 
      minLength: 4, 
      source: function(request, response){             
          var ajaxparam = $('#myinputbox').val(); 
          ajaxparam = escape(ajaxparam);                                                    
          var querystring = "?term=" + ajaxparam;  
          $.ajax({
              url:      'ajax/jsonencode.php'+querystring,
              beforeSend: function(){
                alert("beforeSend");
              },
              async:    true,
              dataType: "json"
          });
      },
      focus: function ( event,ui ){     
          $( "#myinputbox" ).val( ui.item.value );
          return false;            
      },  
      select: function( event, ui ) {          
              $( "#myinputbox" ).val( ui.item.value );
              return false;
      }        

  })
  .data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li></li>" )
                  .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
                  .append( "<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>" )
                  .appendTo( ul );
  };  
}); 
</script>
```

beforeSend fires ok. If I add:

```
                success: function(data){
                  alert(data);
                }
```

...after the dataType, it properly alerts me [object Object].

The json looks like:

```
[
  {
      "value": "value1",
      "desc": "Description 1"
  },
  {
      "value": "value2",
      "desc": "Description 2"
  }
]
```

The json returned passes validation at jsonlint.

The _renderItem does not seem to work.

Any pointers or solution would be appreciated.

Comment: What does your JSON look like? Could you provide a sample?

Comment: If you can, please help out with the next part of this at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403982/setting-validation-range-with-jquery-autocomplete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `$.ajax` call, you're not specifying a `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/jsonencode.php'+querystring,
    beforeSend: function(){
        alert("beforeSend");
    },
    async:    true,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Since the widget expects you to invoke the `response` function to supply the suggestions, you should do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/jsonencode.php'+querystring,
    beforeSend: function(){
        alert("beforeSend");
    },
    async:    true,
    dataType: "json",
    success: response
});
```

That assumes your data has at least a `label` or `value` property.

Comment: Can I have other properties in addition to a label or value? Should I always include both label and value in the json?

Comment: @Cymbals: Good question. You can specify `label` and/or `value`. If the value you want in the `input` is different than the item in the autocomplete dropdown, make `label` and `value` different things, respectively. Otherwise you just need one of the two. You can have any other properties you want and they'll be available as properties of `ui.item` in autocomplete event handlers.

Comment: I added success: response   ...as mentioned above, but no change.

Comment: @Cymbals: Do you see a response in FireBug or another tool? Also, try removing the `_renderItem` code just to see if it works without that

Comment: Removed _renderItem. no change. Firebug doesn't work in FF8 yet. Trying to look at it via developer tools in Chrome.

Comment: correction - that fixed it!! Google Chrome Firebug Lite revealed a bug I introduced in the server side file when prepping the json for the StackOverflow question. Thank you!!!

Comment: If you can, please help me with the next part of this at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330096/jquery-reusable-autocomplete-function